# Returning column name with value_counts in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have code that return value-counts on a column .I would like to return the column name along with value_count value.

```
df = pd.read_excel('Carriers.xlsx')

df1=df['CARRIER'].value_counts()

df1.to_excel('value_counts.xlsx',index=False)
```

This is the input data:

[image]

I am expecting this as output xlsx:

[image]

Comment: Add .reset_index after value_counts().  You columns are in the index and since you are saying index=False you're not getting the index.

Comment: I am getting  this:
CARRIER 0
522        7
1617 8
3350 10

I would like to have title "Count" as column heading for the second column instead of 0

Answer (score 1):

For a dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"CARRIER": [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3]})
```

```
CARRIER
1    2
2    1
3    3
```

Use `value_counts`, then reset the index and change the column name:

```
df = df.value_counts().reset_index().rename(columns={'count': 'Count'})
```

```
   CARRIER  Count
0        1      2
1        2      1
2        3      3
```

Comment: thanks, I would like to add column title "Count" in the returned xslx file

Comment: @syed Change the column name at the end. I've edited the answer.

Comment: do you mean
df=df.groupby('CARRIER').value_counts().reset_index().rename(columns={'0':'Count'})
because i never get count in the first place to raname as Count, i get 0 as column title, but still the above code is not renaming the column title

Comment: What version of Pandas are you using? For Pandas 2+, the column will be named `count`. If you're using a previous version and it's unnamed, you can rename the columns with: `df.columns = ['CARRIER', 'Count']` (in this case, remove the `.rename(...)` that is in the answer).

Comment: sorry still not working:
Input